# Setting @EnableGemFireHttpSession regionName dynamically

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Is there any way to provide GemFire regionName dynamically during runtime. Currently we are hardCoding the regionName "testRegion". Sample Code is below. Appreciate any help

```
@Configuration
@EnableGemFireHttpSession(poolName = "gemfirePool", regionName="testRegion")
public class TestConfig {

//Some Code here

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, great timing! There is now as of *Spring Session for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire* `2.0.5.RELEASE` as well as `2.1.0.M1`.  See [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-session-data-geode-build/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/#httpsession-gemfire-configuration-properties) and alternatively, [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-session-data-geode-build/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/#httpsession-gemfire-configuration-configurer).

I recently made the announcement (and blog) with these changes, [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/08/30/spring-session-for-apache-geode-pivotal-gemfire-2-0-5-release-and-2-1-0-m1-released).

Comment: It worked for me with the 2.0.5 version. Thanks John Blum for the valuable information